# how to draw quarter circle in xml android

Tags: java, android, xml, draw

I want to draw a quarter circle like this.
[image: android xml drawable]

is there any method to do like this shape using xml shape?

Comment: _I want to draw a quarter circle_ What have you tried so far achieving this goal?

Comment: You can draw it by using canvas or give padding in minus.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your can use below rectangle shape .xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:height="15dp" android:width="15dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/darkGray"/>
    <corners android:topRightRadius="0dp" android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```